# Redirect all other pages than the ones specified in my "301 redirect URLs"

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a list of specific pages I redirect with the "Redirect 301" rule.

Now I'm looking to redirect all the other pages I didn't specificaly mention in this list.

How can I do that?

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?parachute\-club\-cannes\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://parachute-club-cannes.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 

# Same for HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.parachute-club-cannes\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://parachute-club-cannes.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 

# 301 Redirect URLs.
Redirect 301 /www.pccannes.com http://www.parachute-club-cannes.com
```

Comment: Can you show your current rules?

Comment: RewriteEngine on
# Redirect to another domain: www.parachute-club-cannes.com.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?parachute\-club\-cannes\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.parachute-club-cannes.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Same for HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?parachute\-club\-cannes\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.parachute-club-cannes.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# 301 Redirect URLs.
Redirect 301 /www.pccannes.com http://www.parachute-club-cannes.com

My list of specific redirects..

Comment: .htaccess should be placed in question not in comments. I tried copy/pasting it in your question, check if it is correct. Also clarify what your requirement is.